# Form content shown in display

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, mapping

Given email given password given address given address2 given city given state given zipcode checkbox value

```js
const store=()=>{
    var Pass = document.getElementById("inputPassword4");
    var Add1 = document.getElementById("inputAddress");
    var Add2 = document.getElementById("inputAddress2");
    var City = document.getElementById("inputCity");
    var State = document.getElementById("inputState");
    var Zip = document.getElementById("inputZip");
    var Email = document.getElementById("inputEmail4");
    var Check = document.getElementById("gridCheck");
    let text= " ";
    let a = [Email?.value,Pass?.value,Add1?.value,Add2?.value,City?.value,State?.value,Zip?.value,Check?.value];
    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = text;
    const display=(item)=>{
        item +=`<li>` + item + `</li>`;
    }
     a.map(display);
}
```

```html
<div class="display">
  <ul id="show">

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the question or problem?

Comment: One issue is that you're not returning anything inside your [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML to make a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to show something,

Here is a simpler version

```js
const fieldNames = ["inputPassword4",
  "inputAddress",
  "inputAddress2",
  "inputCity",
  "inputState",
  "inputZip",
  "inputEmail4",
  "gridCheck"
];
const store = () => {
  const vals = fieldNames
    .map(fieldName => document.getElementById(fieldName)?.value ?? "")
    .filter(val => val != "");
  show.innerHTML = vals.map(val => '<li>${val}</li>`)
};
store();
```